# How to preserve hash fragment of the URL, while implementing SSO using Shibboleth

Tags: jquery, single-sign-on, single-page-application, saml, shibboleth

I have implemented SSO on a single page application using Shibboleth Service Provider. The problem is, when the user tries to access a bookmarked url with hash value, its loosing the hash part of the url after performing authentication at Identity provider(in my case, its ping server). From the second request onwards, it works fine.

For example, if user tries to access https://example.com/index.html#id:12, it is taking me to https://example.com/index.html

> Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:302 Moved
>   Response Header
>   Cache-Control:private,no-store,no-cache,max-age=0
>   Content-Length:40 
>   Content-Type:text/html   Date:Fri, 16 Jun 2017 15:37:41 GMT
>   Expires:Wed, 01 Jan 1997 12:00:00 GMT
>   Location:**https://example.com/index.html**
>   Server:
>   SetCookie:_shibsession_64656661756c746572612d6465465722d656c6563747269632e636f6d=_ad223f20f29ee122537dab8fdd;
>   path=/; secure; HttpOnly
>    X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Looks like, shibboleth is not maintaining the hash value while performing redirection. If you see the Location, it does not hold the hash value. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't know the Shibboleth product intimately, I would recommend trying to URL encode your URL before including it with your federation.

Example:

Instead of https://example.com/index.html#id:12

It would be https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.html%23id%3A12

This may yield better behaviour when you interact with the IDP.